# Case SQL query based on priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have user table with columns like user_id and user_details. In user_details column, it contains the JSON data in string format as shown below:

```
"[{"value":"sachin","label":"What's your first name?"},{"value":"test@example.com","label":"What's your email?"},{"value":"+911234567890","label":"What's your phone number?"},{"value":"xyz","label":"What's your city?"},{"value":"abc","label":"What's your address?"}]"
```

It will contain data in name and value pair in user_details column as shown above.

I want a sql query for find the value from user_details column, if label contains "name" or "email" or "phone number" then show the respective value.
Example - 1:

```
"[{"value":"sachin","label":"What's your first name?"},{"value":"test@example.com","label":"What's your email?"},{"value":"+911234567890","label":"What's your phone number?"},{"value":"xyz","label":"What's your city?"},{"value":"abc","label":"What's your address?"}]"
```

In this example, SQL query should produce the following output:

name | sachin

Example - 2:

```
"[{"value":"test@example.com","label":"What's your email?"},{"value":"+911234567890","label":"What's your phone number?"},{"value":"xyz","label":"What's your city?"},{"value":"abc","label":"What's your address?"}]"
```

In this it should be:
email | test@example.com

Example - 3:

```
"[{"value":"+911234567890","label":"What's your phone number?"},{"value":"xyz","label":"What's your city?"},{"value":"abc","label":"What's your address?"}]"
```

In this it should be:
phone | +911234567890

Example - 4:

```
"[{"value":"xyz","label":"What's your city?"},{"value":"abc","label":"What's your address?"}]"
```

In this it should be:
id | 5
(In this example we don't have name,email or phone number then query should return the id i.e the primary key for that row.)

I tried using case query, but it didn't seem to work. Is there a way to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others, you really ought to change your database schema. However, if you're stuck with the current setup, this query might meet your needs:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%name%', null, '$[*].label')
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'name'
       WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%email%', null, '$[*].label') 
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'email'
       WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%phone number%', null, '$[*].label') 
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'phone'
       ELSE 'id'
  END type,
  CASE WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%name%', null, '$[*].label') 
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN json_unquote(json_extract(user_details, 
              concat(
                json_unquote(
                  replace(
                    json_search(user_details, 'one', '%name%', null, '$[*].label'), 
                    '.label', '')),
                '.value')))
       WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%email%', null, '$[*].label') 
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN json_unquote(json_extract(user_details, 
              concat(
                json_unquote(
                  replace(
                    json_search(user_details, 'one', '%email%', null, '$[*].label'), 
                    '.label', '')),
                '.value')))

       WHEN json_search(user_details, 'one', '%phone number%', null, '$[*].label') 
         IS NOT NULL
       THEN json_unquote(json_extract(user_details, 
              concat(
                json_unquote(
                  replace(
                    json_search(user_details, 'one', '%phone%', null, '$[*].label'), 
                    '.label', '')),
                '.value')))
       ELSE user_id
  END value
FROM json_user;
```